# FormApp.GridItem.setRows() generate new columns in the linked Sheet - any workaround solution?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use a grid in Google Form and a little Google Apps script after every form submit. This script check the availability of the items of the grid.

My problem is if i check the stock and generate the rows after every submit the form generates the same columns in the linked Sheet again and again.

### Example:

**Original Form items:**

- Apple
- Pineapple
- Banana

**Table**:
Apple | Pineapple | Banana

**re-generated Form items:**

- Apple
- Banana

**Table**:
Apple | Pineapple | Banana | Apple | Banana

---

and my code here it is:

```
function availableSlots(){    
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<URL>/edit'); 
  var slots = SpreadsheetApp
                .getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getRange("slots!A2:C20")
                .getValues(); 
  var choice = [];
  for (s in slots){
    if (slots[s][0] != "" && slots[s][2] > 0){
      choice.push(slots[s][0]); 
    }
  }
  var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID); 
    formItems[0].asGridItem().setRows(choice)

}
```

Is there any workaround solution? Tips?

I think I have to merge the new and old columns in every time when the new one generated but I can't imagine how can i do that automatically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about just looking at the header row and see if the columns are not already there before you add them